# How to get list item's leading dot inside the container

Tags: html, css

Sorry if this is an duplicated entry, I tried my best to figured it out but failed.
So I am having markup below, which is a `ul` element inside the `nav` element.

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>A</li>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

And the style for this code sections are

```
nav {
  width: 150px;
  float: right;
}
```

When I open up Chrome's developer tools, I noticed that all the list items' dots are outside the `nav` box. The box is the shadowed area in the screenshot. Is there anyway I can get all those dots inside the box?[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get UL to stay within their containing DIVs?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461015/ul-dont-stay-within-their-containing-divs)

Comment: Oh, yes. I must have missed that. Sorry. @JoshC

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use CSS...

```
nav ul {
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

This bring the discs inside the container.